# Listiview Scrolling Down-Up Changes row's color

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I'm using a listview with adapter inside for changing backcolor in every row according value Active.
Also i'm using holder in my adapter but every time i'm scrolling down and up my listview,  all colors are been changed.

Here is my Class:

```
class FactClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]

    public int id { get; set; } // AutoIncrement and set primarykey        

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int Active { get; set; }//According this Values ListView is changing Color

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        DataViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.FactAdapter, null, false);
            holder = new DataViewHolder();

            holder.txtid = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.idtxt);
            holder.txtName = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Nametxt);
           holder.txtPhone = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Phonetxt);
           holder.txtActive = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Activetxt);

            convertView.Tag = holder;

        }
        else
        {

            holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;

        }

       holder.txtid.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].id);
       holder.txtName.Text = mitems[position].Name;
       holder.txtPhone.Text = mitems[position].Phone;


        holder.txtActive.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].Active);

        if (holder.txtActive.Text == "1")
        {
            holder.txtName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGreen);
            holder.txtPhone.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGreen);
        }
        if (holder.txtActive.Text == "2")
        {
            holder.txtName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);
            holder.txtPhone.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);
        }
        return convertView;

    }

    public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtid { get; set; }
        public TextView txtName { get; set; }
        public TextView txtPhone { get; set; }
        public TextView txtActive { get; set; }


    }
```

The TextView txtActive is responsible for which color will take my row.
Example if txtActive =1 row is green, txtActive =2 row is orange

[Image Before scrolling listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxERd.jpg)

[Image after Scolling Down and up again my listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3zjp.jpg)

Another row has automatically changed his color.

Comment: I think your `if (holder.txtActive.Text == "2")` should be `else if` and what if your `holder.txtActive.Text` isn't 1 or 2 don't you need an else case for that as well.

Comment: Same Result. I think that i need to create tag in txtActive(in my situation).And then to use it if Tag!=null......rest of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used ListViews in the past with multiple holders, but I think your `GetView` holder pattern isn't quite right. I think it should look something more like this.

```
    override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        DataViewHolder holder = null;

        var view = convertView;
        if(view != null)
        {
            holder = view.Tag as DataViewHolder;
        }

        if (holder == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.FactAdapter, null, false);
            holder = new DataViewHolder();

            holder.txtid = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.idtxt);
            holder.txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Nametxt);
            holder.txtPhone = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Phonetxt);
            holder.txtActive = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Activetxt);

            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        holder.txtid.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].id);
        holder.txtName.Text = mitems[position].Name;
        holder.txtPhone.Text = mitems[position].Phone;

        holder.txtActive.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].Active);

        if (holder.txtActive.Text == "1")
        {
            holder.txtName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGreen);
            holder.txtPhone.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGreen);
        }
        else if (holder.txtActive.Text == "2")
        {
            holder.txtName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);
            holder.txtPhone.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);
        }
        else
        {
           holder.txtName.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
           holder.txtPhone.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Also, here's a great [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/) with more information about Android ListViews and holders.